# Error: argument "map" is missing in R while plotting data in a state map

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am trying to match the AQL value of each county in Wisconsin into the county map , and use colors to indicate AQL level. I use `ggplot2` and `maps` packages in R.

Here is my data dataframe:

```
> head(query)
        name      AQL  subregion
1    Ashland 22.39474    ashland
2      Brown 32.77049      brown
3       Dane 36.56000       dane
4      Dodge 34.44000      dodge
5 Eau Claire 33.00000 eau claire
6     Forest 19.94118     forest

# Get wisconsin county map data
> county_map = map_data("county", "wisconsin")
```

I tried to use `geom_map()` as following:

```
p5 = ggplot(query, aes(map_id = subregion)) +
        geom_map(aes(fill = AQL, map = county_map)) +
        expand_limits(x = county_map$long, y = county_map$lat) +
        scale_fill_gradient(low = "#ff7b75", high = "#5b0300", space = "Lab")
p5
```

Then it gets an error:

> Error in is.data.frame(map) : argument "map" is missing, with no default

How can I solve this error? Or are there other ways to plot my `query` with `county_map`? Thanks!

Comment: don't put it in the `aes()`. `map_id` belongs in `aes()` not `map`. That needs to be outside `aes()`.

Comment: @hrbrmstr Thanks! Do you mean like this `ggplot(query, aes(map_id = subregion)) + geom_map(aes(fill = AQL), map = county_map) + expand_limits(x = county_map$long, y = county_map$lat)`? It gives me another error `Error in unit(x, default.units) : 'x' and 'units' must have length > 0`.